# How to apply Empirical Line Method to UAS imagery for radiometric correction

Tags: digital-image-processing, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, radiometric, correction, calibration

I am correcting/calibrating multispectral UAS imagery using the Empirical Line Method using the raw digital number of 3 color panels (white, 18% grey, black). I found the slope and the intercept of the line and applied the equation to the raw digital numbers from my imagery, but the corrected values in my rasters have reflectances > 1 and < 0. (represented by yellow highlighted areas on the graph). Do I set all pixels with Reflectance < 0 to 0 and Reflectance > 1 to 1? Do I leave them as-is and let there be Reflectance values outside of 0 and 1?

[image: Schematic of Empirical Line Method from Olosson et al. 2021]